# iPhone - didPopItem ? Is this supposed to work?

Tags: iphone

I have a simple UITableView setup. I am trying to use

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
```

I put a NSLog inside this method, but it is apparently not getting called when I "pop" back to the screen. I am not finding much information about this function, has it been replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your table view controller as the navigation bar's delegate?